# How to include the start url in the "allow" rule in SgmlLinkExtractor using a scrapy crawl spider

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I have searched a lot of topics but does not seem to find the answer for my specific question.
I have created a crawl spider for a website and it works perfectly. I then made a similar one to crawl a similar website but this time I have a small issue. Down to the business:

my start url looks as follows: www.example.com . The page contains the links I want to apply my spider look like:

- www.example.com/locationA
- www.example.com/locationB
- www.example.com/locationC

...

I now have a issue:
Every time when I enter the start url, it redirects to  www.example.com/locationA automatically and all links I got my spider working include

- www.example.com/locationB
- www.example.com/locationC
  ...

So my problem is how I can include the www.example.com/locationA in the returned URLs.I even got the log info like:

-2011-11-28 21:25:33+1300 [example.com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to  from http://www.example.com/>

-2011-11-28 21:25:34+1300[example.com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to  (referer: None)

- 2011-11-28 21:25:37+1300 [example.com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to  (referer: www.example.com/locationB)

Print out from parse_item:  www.example.com/locationB

....

I think the issue might be related to that (referer: None) some how. Could anyone please shed some light on this??

I have narrow down this issue by changing the start url to www.example.com/locationB. Since all the pages contain the lists of all locations, this time I got my spider works on:

-www.example.com/locationA

-www.example.com/locationC
...

In a nut shell, I am looking for the way to include the url which is same as (or being redirected from) the start url into the list that the parse_item callback will work on.

Comment: Could you include a short example from your scraper to help us understand your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 14):

For others have the same problem, after a lot of searching, all you need to do is name your callback function to `parse_start_url`.

**Eg:**

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=(
            '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "pagination-next", " " ))]//a',)), callback="parse_start_url", follow=True),
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding sample code based on mindcast suggestion:

```
I manage using following approach

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "examplespider"
allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
start_urls = ['http://example.com/A']


rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//div[@id='tag_cloud']/a",)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    self.log('>>>>>>>> PARSE START URL: %s' % response)
    # www.example.com/A will be parsed here
    return self.parse_items(response)

def parse_items(self, response):
    self.log('>>>>>>>> PARSE ITEM FROM %s' % response.url)
    """Scrape data from links based on Crawl Rules"""
```

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that there is a simple solution using `start_requests()` like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('START_URL_HERE', callback=self.parse_item)
```

But tests showed, that when `start_requests()` is used instead of a `start_urls` list, spider ignores `rules`, because `CrawlSpider.parse(response)` is not called.

So, here is my solution:

```
import itertools
class SomeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    ....
    start_urls = ('YOUR_START_URL',)
    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'YOUR_REGEXP',),),
            follow=True,
            callback='parse_item'),
        ),
    )
    def parse(self, response):
        return itertools.chain(
                     CrawlSpider.parse(self, response), 
                     self.parse_item(response))

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield item
```

Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to specifically add a rule for the start_urls(in your case: http://example.com/locationA )(please ignore indentation issue):

```
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "examplespider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = ['http://example.com/locationA']

  rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('locationA')), callback='parse_item'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('location\.*?'),restrict_css=('.pagination-next',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
  )

  def parse_item(self, response):
       self.log('>>>>>>>> PARSE ITEM FROM %s' % response.url)
```